# Express One-to-Many relationship in Entity Framework via join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many, join

In database design, a common practice is to express a one-to-many relationship with a foreign key on the "one" (or child) side.  Entity framework handles this situation well.

However, I have the situation where a one-to-many relationship is expressed via a join table in which one of the two foreign keys on the table has a unique constraint.

How can Entity Framework be configured to utilize this join table?

In my current state, when doing a simple read query on the one/child entity, Entity Frameworks is throwing an exception---as expected---that the one/child table is missing a column by the conventional name based on the navigation property.

Comment: If you have a join table.....then (even if there db constraints to guarantee a 1:N) , you must treat the EF part as M:N.  You can write a (get only) property on the EF-Entity that would bring back the FirstOrDefault() that would bring back your "one" in the 1:N.

Comment: @granadaCoder Oo, I like that.  I will try it and report back.

Comment: @granadaCoder But it should be a get-only property.  It should have a setter that adds it to the collection.

Comment: That's fine too.  Just so you know the setter is not a simple setter.

Comment: I am out of my imagination: one-many with a join table? Could you add a diagram for slower guys like myself.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Have you read about (the forms of) [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?  I think expressing one-to-one and one-to-many relationships via a join tables is a "more normalized" form (but I don't remember exactly).

Comment: I just thought your question would be more interesting with a diagram of your 3 tables.

Comment: @VD.  In my answer, I have Department to Employee as the FK in the child table.  But you can also see the setup the poster as made with the Employee to ParkingArea relationship.  I use this rule when "today, I think there will only be a 1:N, BUT sometime in the future I could foresee a M:N"...so I go ahead and code for it to expand to M:N at a later time.  the Employee to ParkingArea DDL below shows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have the below DDL.

Employee (M:N) to ParkingArea.  However, a constraint keeps only one Employee in the link table, thus a 1:N.

-- START TSQL

```
Use OrganizationReverseDB
GO


SET NOCOUNT ON


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] 
END 
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[ParkingArea]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[ParkingArea] 
END 
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Employee]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
END 


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Employee]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
END 


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Department]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
END 

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    )


ALTER TABLE dbo.[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Department PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([DepartmentUUID]) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DepartmentName_Unique UNIQUE ([DepartmentName]) 
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ( 

    [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeUUID) 
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO





IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[ParkingArea]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[ParkingArea] 
END 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParkingArea] 
( 
ParkingAreaUUID [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() 
, ParkingAreaName varchar(24) not null 
, CreateDate smalldatetime not null
)

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ParkingArea ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ParkingArea PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ParkingAreaUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParkingArea] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ParkingAreaName_Unique UNIQUE (ParkingAreaName) 
GO



IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] 
END 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] ( 
    /* [LinkSurrogateUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, */
    [TheEmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheParkingAreaUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)


GO

/*
ALTER TABLE dbo.EmployeeParkingAreaLink ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeeParkingAreaLink PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (LinkSurrogateUUID) 
*/
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeParkingAreaLinkToEmployee FOREIGN KEY (TheEmployeeUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Employee (EmployeeUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeParkingAreaLinkToParkingArea FOREIGN KEY (TheParkingAreaUUID) REFERENCES dbo.ParkingArea (ParkingAreaUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] ADD CONSTRAINT CONST_UNIQUE_EmpUUID UNIQUE (TheEmployeeUUID ) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] ADD CONSTRAINT CONST_UNIQUE_EmpUUID_PAUUID UNIQUE (TheEmployeeUUID , TheParkingAreaUUID) 
GO


Insert into dbo.Department ( [DepartmentUUID], [DepartmentName] , CreateDate )
    select '10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' , 'DepartmentOne' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    union all   select '10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002' , 'DepartmentTwo' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Insert into dbo.Employee ( EmployeeUUID, SSN , CreateDate, HireDate , LastName, FirstName , ParentDepartmentUUID)
    select '20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' , '111-11-1111' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , '01/31/2001' , 'Smith' , 'John' , '10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'
    union all   select '20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002' , '222-22-2222' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '02/28/2002' , 'Jones' , 'Mary' , '10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'

Insert into dbo.ParkingArea ( [ParkingAreaUUID], [ParkingAreaName] , CreateDate )
    select '30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' , 'ParkingAreaOne' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    union all   select '30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002' , 'ParkingAreaTwo' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeParkingAreaLink] (   [TheEmployeeUUID] , [TheParkingAreaUUID] )
        Select '20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' , '30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'
union all       Select '20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002' , '30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'
```

Where the constraint "CONST_UNIQUE_EmpUUID" is the setup of which you are speaking.

EmployeeEntity like this:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class EmployeeEFEntity
{

public EmployeeEFEntity()
{
    CommonConstructor();
}
private void CommonConstructor()
{
    //this.MyParkingAreas = new List<ParkingAreaEFEntity>();
}



//EF Tweaks
public virtual Guid? ParentDepartmentUUID { get; set; }

public virtual Guid? EmployeeUUID { get; set; }

public virtual byte[] TheVersionProperty { get; set; }

public virtual DepartmentEFEntity ParentDepartment { get; set; }

public virtual string SSN { get; set; }
public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ParkingAreaEFEntity> MyParkingAreas { get; set; }

public ParkingAreaEFEntity MyOneParkingAreaEFEntity {

    get 
    {
        return MyParkingAreas.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    set
    {
        /* check for more than one here */
        this.AddParkingArea(pa);
    }
}


public virtual void AddParkingArea(ParkingAreaEFEntity pa)
{
    if (!pa.MyEmployees.Contains(this))
    {
        pa.MyEmployees.Add(this);
    }
    if (!this.MyParkingAreas.Contains(pa))
    {
        this.MyParkingAreas.Add(pa);
    }
}


public virtual void RemoveParkingArea(ParkingAreaEFEntity pa)
{
    if (pa.MyEmployees.Contains(this))
    {
        pa.MyEmployees.Remove(this);
    }
    if (this.MyParkingAreas.Contains(pa))
    {
        this.MyParkingAreas.Remove(pa);
    }
}


public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}:{1},{2}", this.SSN, this.LastName, this.FirstName);
}
```

You would map like this:

```
public class EmployeeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EmployeeEFEntity>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.EmployeeUUID);

        this.Property(t => t.EmployeeUUID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.TheVersionProperty)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        this.Property(t => t.SSN)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(11);

        this.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Employee");
        this.Property(t => t.EmployeeUUID).HasColumnName("EmployeeUUID");
        this.Property(t => t.ParentDepartmentUUID).HasColumnName("ParentDepartmentUUID");
        this.Property(t => t.TheVersionProperty).HasColumnName("TheVersionProperty");
        this.Property(t => t.SSN).HasColumnName("SSN");
        this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateDate).HasColumnName("CreateDate");
        this.Property(t => t.HireDate).HasColumnName("HireDate");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.MyParkingAreas)
            .WithMany(t => t.MyEmployees)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("EmployeeParkingAreaLink");
                m.MapLeftKey("TheEmployeeUUID");
                m.MapRightKey("TheParkingAreaUUID");
            });

        this.HasRequired(t => t.ParentDepartment)
            .WithMany(t => t.Employees)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentDepartmentUUID);

    }
}
```

ParkingArea like this:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class ParkingAreaEFEntity
{

    public ParkingAreaEFEntity()
    {
        CommonConstructor();
    }
    private void CommonConstructor()
    {
        //this.MyEmployees = new List<EmployeeEFEntity>();
    }

    public virtual Guid ParkingAreaUUID { get; set; }


    public virtual string ParkingAreaName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeEFEntity> MyEmployees { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddEmployee(EmployeeEFEntity emp)
    {
        if (!emp.MyParkingAreas.Contains(this))
        {
            emp.MyParkingAreas.Add(this);
        }
        if (!this.MyEmployees.Contains(emp))
        {
            this.MyEmployees.Add(emp);
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveEmployee(EmployeeEFEntity emp)
    {
        if (emp.MyParkingAreas.Contains(this))
        {
            emp.MyParkingAreas.Remove(this);
        }
        if (this.MyEmployees.Contains(emp))
        {
            this.MyEmployees.Remove(emp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this example could have been simplified greatly, I think it does exhibit your comment to "lie" to EF and say the join name is for a many-to-many relationship.  I want to highlight the important part for other readers...namely, in the class `EmployeeMap` (which is the fluent EF configuration for `EmployeeEFEntity`), the `HasMany.(-).WithMany(-).Map(-)` is where we are "lying" to EF and specifying the join table.

Comment: Also, in my setup (though I will use the naming in your example), I needed to add the configuration `Ignore(x => x.MyOneParkingAreaEFEntity)` so that EF doesn't think there is a column in the database by the name `MyOneParkingAreaEFEntity_ID`.

Comment: That's the example I keep around for POC stuff.  Once you solve a 1:N, a M:N (with no attributes on the relationship), an M:N (with attributes on the relationship) and a lookup table.......most things can be derived from that.

Comment: Right, MyOneParkingAreaEFEntity has to be ignored as far as EF is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is *optional one-to-many association with a join table*. The motivation behind this is that we always try to avoid nullable columns in a relational database schema. Information that is unknown degrades the quality of the data you store. Therefore, an optional entity association, be it one-to-one or one-to-many, is best represented in an SQL database with a join table to avoid nullable foreign key columns.

All that being said, EF unfortunately does *not* support this type of mapping. If you really want to implement this then you might want to take a look at other ORM Frameworks that support one-to-many association with a join table like *NHibernate*.